# Bootstrap: large centered logo navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, navbar

I wouuld like to make the logo appear **larger and centered** above the navbar. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code: [https://jsfiddle.net/ou51rksb/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ou51rksb/1/)

```
<body class="home">
    <!-- wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper" class="win-min-height">
        <header id="block01g" class="header block background01" zp-module="Header">
            <div class="container header_block">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img class="blacklogo img-responsive" src="images/logob.png" alt="Bañuelos Refrigeration Services">
                    <img class="whitelogo img-responsive" src="images/logob.png" alt="Bañuelos Refrigeration Services">
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: does the answer help you, please provide some feedback

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:absolute;` for `navbar-brand`. Add this to your css:

```
.header_block{
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  padding-top:45px;
}
.navbar-brand{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  height:70px;
  transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
.navbar-brand img{
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ou51rksb/6/). You have set some padding at the top of your body. which you can remove. that will get your logo aligned to the top.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me where to remove the padding at the top of the body?

Comment: I got it centered with your styles but I still can't get it to display in a larger size. Maybe when the padding is removed, it will display correctly.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, can you set up a fiddle of your current code.

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/a0da4ew1/2/  . The changes I have made start from the following comment in the bottom of the fiddle `/*This is where the edit starts.*/`

Comment: to change the logo-size. just change the `padding-top` in `.header_block`. right now it is set to 75px.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this css

```
#block01g .navbar-brand {
  display: block;
  float: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;//you add width for logo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this i have centered your logo simply , is this what you need ?

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ou51rksb/12/